# Running multiple services

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I'm currently building some movement-detection functionality into my application. I haven't found a way of continually monitoring the accelerometer without keeping the phone awake all the time. In trying to overcome this, I currently have a Service implementing SensorEventListener. I can start this service at intervals (using alarm manager), get readings from the device acclerometer, determine if the device is moving, and then shut down the service. Generally, this appears as follows:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
                /* Register this SensorEventListener with Android sensor service */
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        /* Unregister SensorEventListener */
        }

    /* SensorEventListener Implementation ************************/

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    /* Receives callback when sensor values change */
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        /* Determine if moving & then call stopSelf() to shut service down */
    }
}
```

I have a further problem, however, in that my application has a second service which is invoked on a different schedule. As far as I know, both of the services will be run in the same thread, which is not good as they could conflict.

**I need to know if there is a safe way to run more than one service simultaneously within the same application**. I have considered the use of IntentService instead of the standard Service class. I am aware that these implement their own worker thread for handling invocations. The problem there is that I have no idea how I can implement the type of asynchronous callbacks required by SensorEventListener from within an IntentService. To put it another way, I have no guarantee that a method like onSensorChanged will receive a callback before IntentService completes its work and shuts down.

Any suggestions on a workaround to this problem are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should mark Commons' answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> as they could conflict.

How?

> I need to know if there is a safe way to run more than one service simultaneously within the same application

There is no intrinsic problem in having more than one service simultaneously within the same application, any more than there is an intrinsic problem in having more than one activity in the same application.

> Any suggestions on a workaround to this problem are highly appreciated.

You have not demonstrated a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for taking the time to answer. In hindsight, my question is poorly phrased... Let me rephrase. If I am invoking two separate services (on different schedules), aren't these both started in the main application (UI) thread by default? If invocations of these services happen to overlap, what are the consequences(if any)? Will both services simply carry out their work (in an unspecified order) without any drastic consequences?

Comment: My understanding says that since both the services will be running on the main thread, the first service triggered will run while the next one will be put onto the message queue for the main thread and will be taken up later. Also, if the first service takes up too long an ANR may be thrown. (I'm not sure of this, but the documentation for a BroadcastReceiver says that ANR will be thrown if the receiver doesn't finish in 10 seconds.)

Comment: @advantej thanks for that explanation. The only work my BroadcastReceiver (which is responding to intents fired by AlarmManager) performs is to start the services, so the receiver's work should be done once the specified service starts. This eliminates the ANR scenario you mention, right?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. But with what you are doing, it seems there shouldn't be any issues as long as you do not perform any long tasks in the Service.

Comment: @advantej: "the first service triggered will run while the next one will be put onto the message queue for the main thread and will be taken up later" -- it will be more on a lifecycle method-by-method basis. Service #1 might be called with `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()`, then Service #2 might be called with `onCreate()`, then Service #1 might get `onDestroy()`, etc.

Comment: @commonsware what about the ANR scenario @declantraynor is asking ?

Comment: @advantej: I'm in agreement with you (gave your comment an up-vote). All services, everywhere, need to get in and out of lifecycle methods very very quickly. If you get an ANR, you are spending 100x more time in that method than you should be. Hence, well-written services should not conflict with other services or activities in the application.

Comment: @commonsware @advantej : Thanks for your comments. I can see now that my multiple services work well; as long as I respect the rules when it comes to getting in and out of lifecycle methods ASAP. On a related note, do either of you know if there is any concept of assigning priority to services? For example, is there a way that I can ensure that service 1 always runs before service 2, if invocations of the two were to overlap?

Comment: @declantraynor: "For example, is there a way that I can ensure that service 1 always runs before service 2, if invocations of the two were to overlap?" -- no, sorry. If they are that closely coupled, they should not be two services. Have one service serve in both roles.

Comment: Is there a point in running two services just for code separation? Should I instead run two handler threads from a single service?

Comment: @Locutus: "Is there a point in running two services just for code separation?" -- IMHO, no. "Is there a point in running two services just for code separation? Should I instead run two handler threads from a single service" -- threads, maybe, but I don't know what `HandlerThread` would buy you over a regular `Thread`, or a thread pool working off of a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need two logically separate threads that receive and process messages from my application or each other. Each of them further run their own worker threads in their internal executors.

Comment: @CommonsWare is Service for getting data from SensorManager in a different thread is useless? Is it unnecessarly expensive even if service runs in the same process? Is using only thread enough? How do you set SensorManager to run on a different thread?

Comment: @FatihOzcan: "is Service for getting data from SensorManager in a different thread is useless?" -- a `Service` is not a `Thread`. Only use a `Service` when you need one (i.e., you are trying to do work in the background). "Is it unnecessarly expensive even if service runs in the same process?" -- a `Service` on its own does not add overhead. It is all in how you use it. "Is using only thread enough?" -- I would hope so. "How do you set SensorManager to run on a different thread?" -- call the version of `registerReceiver()` that takes a `Handler`, where you get that from a `HandlerThread`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, i know it's not a Thread, it's more like Activity without layout  and with it's own task. I read some of your posts on several threads. I got an impression that you are against `Service` due to it requiring more CPU and RAM, isn't that true even if it does not run on a seperate process? Only excuse for using a Service because it has it's own cycle and can run even if user exist the app, right?

Comment: @FatihOzcan: "it's more like Activity without layout and with it's own task" -- not really. "I got an impression that you are against Service due to it requiring more CPU and RAM" -- I doubt that I have ever written anything like that. I am against unnecessary extra **processes** due to them requiring more CPU and RAM. A `Service` is not a process. "Only excuse for using a Service because it has it's own cycle and can run even if user exist the app, right?" -- generally, yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Isn't dividing workload between processes better if the main process' memory usage is high? Doesn't it make app run more smoothly?

Comment: @CommonsWare, i also have one architectural question about data exchange or communication between multiple threads and services but should i ask it as a separate question? If a worker thread is receiving data from other worker thread and a foreground service with thread is it efficient to use volatile field members or handler is better for memory efficiency? I can ask this question in a separate thread with more details if needed.

Comment: @FatihOzcan: "Isn't dividing workload between processes better if the main process' memory usage is high? Doesn't it make app run more smoothly?" -- I cannot answer that in the abstract. IMHO, the right solution is: stop using so much memory. "should i ask it as a separate question?" -- please. Asking for small clarifications on an answer via comments is fine. IMHO, all of your comments on this answer should have been in a separate question.